# to get all data from start date and end date

Tags: sql, oracle

I wan't to get data from week starting date to week ending date by using sql query.I am able to get that too but the query is not running while for different year like say to get all data from "12/27/2015" to "01/02/2015".
My query is :

```
SELECT * FROM capital 
WHERE capital.ACTIVE = 'T' 
  AND TO_CHAR(capital.CREATE_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '12/27/2015' 
  AND TO_CHAR(capital.SUBMIT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <='01/01/2016' 
  AND capital.TYPE = 'Fiscal'
```

Thanks

Please help me friends

Comment: Because `start date`(**12/27/2015**) is **greater** than `end date`(**01/02/2015**)

Comment: do not convert time to string, you're getting wrong comparison result because of that

Comment: Which DB/Version are you using?

Comment: sorry end date is not (01/02/2015) its (01/02/2016)

Comment: What data types do the columns `create_time` and `submit_time` have? And which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Timestamp and Oracle sql

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change this:

```
AND TO_CHAR(capital.CREATE_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '12/27/2015' 
AND TO_CHAR(capital.SUBMIT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <='01/01/2016'
```

to this

```
AND capital.CREATE_TIME  >= to_date('12/27/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
AND capital.SUBMIT_TIME <= to_date('01/01/2016', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
AND TO_CHAR(capital.CREATE_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= '12/27/2015' 
AND TO_CHAR(capital.SUBMIT_TIME, 'MM/DD/YYYY') <='01/01/2016'
```

`CREATE_TIME` cannot be greater than `SUBMIT_TIME`.

Comment: sorry end date is not (01/02/2015) its (01/02/2016)